# How to overlay two charts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

In Google Sheets, I need two sets to data to appear on the same chart. One needs to be a scatter charts and the other needs to be a line chart. Both sets of data have the same x and y axis data / range. I just need to show both in a single chart using different chart types. How can this be done in Google Sheets?

Comment: I am afraid what you ask for cannot be achieved. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not have a feature to do what you want. However, a work-around may be possible by making the line transparent.

This is untested.

- Create two graphs
- Edit the Line graph to remove the background colour (Customize, Chart Style, Background color=none)
- Drag one graph to physically overlay on the other.
- Format each graph according to requirements.

Comment: This is a kludge, but a good one! To get the graphs to line up I had to make sure the axes min/max, title, labels, formatting, etc. were consistent between the stacked graphs.